# Custom UITableView visibleCells method

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I working with a custom UIScrollView called PSCollectionVIew and now I have to know which of cells are currently visible. But it seems this doesnt have this method.

Is there any way I can implement it by myself ?

I need it to use it in here

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{}
```

thanks  gda

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a ScrollView named CollectionView. This is really confusing. It makes people think your class is a subclass of UICollectionView while it is just a UIScrollView. I suggest you refactor the name.

This is important because on a UICollectionView you have an accessor named

```
- (NSArray *)visibleCells
```

While on UIScrollView as you create and position your items yourself, you need to do it by your own.

Be aware that the collection view handles the memory management by reusing cells instead of allocating every view. You should be considering using UICollectionView but if for some reason you don't, you will have to do the visibleViews (no cells as it is a UIScrollView) by your self.

You should iterate over each sub view and test if the frame intersects the scrollView bounds (visible rect) using [CGRectIntersectsRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect)

Comment: Weird way of using ScrollView. I suggest that you add an issue to the code or implement it your self as described above.